# UIImageView Image assignment and debug

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

When I've created an `UIImageView`, I can see its memory allocation in the debugger.
But I can't find its image property, which supposedly holds the actual image, in the debugger.
The 2 structures under the `UIImageview` in debugger are:

1. UIView
2. _storage

How can I otherwise tell, that a `UIImageView` actually contains an image?

Cheers
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Didn't know if you can check for UIImageView image in debugging 
But you can check anywhere in your code by putting the line :

If(UIImageView.Image == nil )

Maybe this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use GDB command:
*po [yourImageView image]*

**_storage** - it is also a pointer to UIImage, i.e. your **image** property within UIImageView object